# Error al compilar andorid genexus

Tags: genexus

Tengo un error al generar al generar una aplicación que solo me pasa en una kb que cargue en otro equipo adjunto captura, uso genexus 16u6 java 8. en el otro equipo compilaba sin problemas
Alguna ayuda?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

========== SmartDevices (Smart Devices) Generation started ==========
Generating metadata files...
Applying Root Project
Applying Bootstrapping for:AppContableCFE
error: Could not find file 'D:\Proyectos\CFEaExcel\JavaModel\web\gxmetadata\appcontablecfe.apis'.
Failed: SmartDevices (Smart Devices) Generation
========== DeveloperMenu Compilation for Default (Java Web) started ==========
"D:\Proyectos\CFEaExcel\JavaModel\web\callmake.bat" "D:\Proyectos\CFEaExcel\JavaModel\web\GXJMake.exe" "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\bin\javac.exe" developermenu com\cfeaexcel\ options: -O
GeneXus Java Make v1.0
Build succeeded.
Success: DeveloperMenu Compilation for Default (Java Web)
Calculating Mobile Targets for SmartDevices (Smart Devices)
========== Android Compilation started ==========
error: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Proyectos\CFEaExcel\JavaModel\mobile\android\AppContableCFE\src\main\res\raw\images_txt'.
Failed: Android Compilation
Failed: Build All

probe hacer export del XPZ y el import en una nueva KB me da el siguiente error que no me doy cuenta si eso puede ser parte del problema
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pon el error _como texto_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Revisaria en el output del IDE si no tenes errores antes de ese (objetos no generados o similares)

Comment: solo ese error aparece output. lo raro es que es con esa kb, en el anterior equipo funcionaba perfecto.